# Finding the anterior comissure to set origin in a SPECT image using SPM/ISAS

Tags: neuroimaging, spm

I am learning how to use SPM and ISAS to analyze ictal and interictal SPECT. However I am stuck at a point of their [tutorial](http://spect.yale.edu/analysis_details.html#set_origin).

In the item 1.2 one has to set the origin for the SPECT image. That is, to pinpoint the [anterior commissure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anterior_commissure). This is a fairly easy task in a MRI, but very hard to do in a SPECT. How am I to find a tiny anatomical area in such a blurry image (like the one below)?

[image]

Are there any anatomical references that I should be using in order to find the approximate area for the anterior commissure?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Whole Brain Atlas by Harvard](http://www.med.harvard.edu/aanlib/home.html) to [look at the normal brain anatomy in 3-D with MRI/PET](http://www.med.harvard.edu/aanlib/cases/caseNA/pb9.htm).

Check the Anterior Commissure (AC) on the MRI and sync it with the PET or SPECT. It helps.

More specifically, select "Anterior Commissure" and T1/FDG and click sync to show all the orientations in the same modalities and anatomical structure. It helps to find the anterior commissure in a normal brain using nuclear medicine image.

Comment: Thanks, Henrique, however I want to find the anatomical point of interest in the particular image I have in hand. Usually it does not comes with an anatomical image overlayed, and it is really hard to pinpoint the anterior comissure. I guess the answer is that one can never exactly find the anterior comissure when all one has is the SPECT image, w/o the anatomical image to guide... Thanks anyways...